# Create dynamic inline stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way of creating dynamic style tags using js and/or jQuery?

I tried this:

```
var style= jQuery('<style>').text('.test{}');
```

This works in FF but pops an error in IE7 "Unexpected call to method or property access."

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML='.test{}';
```

Gives the same error. It doesn't matter if I use `innerHTML` or `innerText`. The strange thing is that it shows an error before appending the style tag.

I suspect that `cssText` has something to do with it, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I believe that css data is treated differently from text/HTML, so you can't reliably use jQuery text editing methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding text to a stylesheet that will be rendered correctly needs a different syntax in IE than other browsers.
You may be able to use some of this with jquery

```
   document.addStyle= function(str, hoo, med){
     var el= document.createElement('style');
     el.type= "text/css";
     el.media= med || 'screen';
     if(hoo) el.title= hoo;
     if(el.styleSheet) el.styleSheet.cssText= str;//IE only
     else el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
     return document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
    }
```

Comment: Works great. jQuery should abstract this! Any performance issues you know about?

Comment: I often use it with a cookie to persist user display preferences onload, and sometimes to make large style changes on a page instead of looping through elements and applying individual styles.

It has worked well for years in IE,firefox,opera, and safari, even when the stylesheet rules methods were less well supported.

Comment: David see my post for a an abstracted jQuery plugin and notes on using this method in IE.

Comment: It is important for IE<=7 to add styleSheet node ('el' in example above) to head before setting its content. In other case different issues may happen. For example multi class selector ".aaa.bbb" transforms to ".bbb" as a result (it is just one case). See also http://www.phpied.com/dynamic-script-and-style-elements-in-ie/

Answer (score 1):

This method of generating css rules dynamically will be flawed even if it worked. IE will simply ignore `<style>` elements after more then 30 have been inserted (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161).

You can use the [jquery.rule](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html) plugin for the purpose of manipulating css rules through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Javascript's `document.styleSheets`, and the `addRule()` method.

*(Disclaimer: I've never actually used this myself)*