# Invalid assignment left-hand side with ternary if

Tags: javascript

I want to create an stylesheet like this:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style'); sheet.type = 'text/css';
sheet.innerHTML = data.style;
```

But [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041495/create-dynamic-inline-stylesheet) that IE needs its own syntax. To simplify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2042099/1529630)'s code, I have tried

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style'); sheet.type = 'text/css';
(sheet.styleSheet ? sheet.styleSheet.cssText : sheet.innerHTML) = data.style;
```

But that throws `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`.

Then, must I use...

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style'); sheet.type = 'text/css';
if(sheet.styleSheet) sheet.styleSheet.cssText = data.style;
else sheet.innerHTML = data.style;
```

... or is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: I believe you can get away with setting both values, and Javascript's object system is robust enough to take care of the difference.

Comment: @abiessu But if `sheet.styleSheet` is `undefined`, then `sheet.styleSheet.cssText = sheet.innerHTML = data.style` throws `TypeError: sheet.styleSheet is undefined`. Then, I should also check if I should create the object `sheet.styleSheet`

Comment: No, I mean using two separate assignment lines.  That type error is very likely thrown because `sheet.stylesheet` does not exist for the purpose of providing a value accessible to `sheet.styleSheet.cssText` in your example.

Comment: @abiessu Well, it's the same

Comment: Just make a convenience function for setting it and forget about it.

Comment: In the broad scheme of things, using two explicit `if` statements for your stylesheet is unlikely to cause either significant performance issues or significant confusion for maintenance purposes.  I don't know of any other simple alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do :

```
sheet.styleSheet ? sheet.styleSheet.cssText = data.style 
                 : sheet.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.style));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WAYJF/1/)

Comment: @Dave - but it does answer the question!

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid repeating `data.style`, but I guess this is the most simplified working code

Comment: @Oriol the code I posted avoids repeating `data.style` (that's the only advantage of setting up a function. Well that and future maintainability). This answer's a bit more readable since gaining a newline, but personally, I'd still strongly recommend using more readable code. As I said in my other comment, use a compiler if you want it small. It will make optimisations like this anyway for your release version, while leaving the original code easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution which won't leave future maintainers wondering what on earth the code does:

```
function setSheetContent( sheet, text ) {
    if(sheet.styleSheet)
        sheet.styleSheet.cssText = text;
    else
        sheet.innerHTML = text;
}

var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.type = 'text/css';
setSheetContent( sheet, data.style );
```

or wrap it up for even more convenience (if you never want to change the content of an existing sheet)

```
function stylesheetWithContent( sheet, text ) {
    var sheet = document.createElement('style');
    sheet.type = 'text/css';
    if(sheet.styleSheet)
        sheet.styleSheet.cssText = text;
    else
        sheet.innerHTML = text;
    return sheet;
}

var sheet = stylesheetWithContent( data.style );
```

Comment: Also don't put lots of statements on one line. If you want to minify the code for faster downloads, use an actual minifier (Google Closure Compiler has an online version, for example)

Comment: I only used `var sheet = document.createElement('style'); sheet.type = 'text/css';` on same line because when I write HTML I use `<style type="text/css">` on same line too.

Comment: @Oriol it's still a bit odd. The usual convention is one logical statement per line. In this case, the first to create an element, the second to set its type attribute. HTML isn't a programming language, so the rules are different for it. I've found it's usually a better idea to go with convention than try fighting it; you don't want to spend more time thinking about style than content.